# Could not load file or assembly in windows application

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I am creating  DLL file using c# .For that i need one DLL file. That is created in VB.so i just i add that dll file into my project via add reference option.But when run the projects am getting this error.

Could not load file or assembly 'BOL3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Can  any body give the suggestion to resolve this issue.

Thanks !

Comment: It seems that the dependencies of assembly BOL3 is missing

Comment: Thanks for response ! let me know if add DLL file into the project.Then project contain the all dependencies of assembly BOL3. Is It?

Comment: if you have added the reference through project tab, than it will also copy the dependencies while if you have added through Browse, it will only add only that DLL.

Comment: Now i added Dll file from project tab.Even it is giving same error.

Comment: Make sure that BOL3.dll has been copied into the executable file's folder. Unlike Visual Studio, CLR cannot locate
assemblies by project references.

Comment: My orginal DLL file and BOL3.dll file are in same place.(bin\X86\Debug)

Comment: can you got any ideas about my issue.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Make sure the final project have references to all the "child" dlls like as commented if your dll1 uses dll2 then the main proj need to ref it.
2 - Make sure they all compiled in the same bit i.e. 64 or 86, you can choose it from the projecy properties, if 1 is 64 and the other 86 the compiler won't recognize the other.

Comment: So My main project need to contain all reference what child project contain.is it?

Comment: My system is x64.I set Any CPU option.I am getting same error message.